# PainterSVG can not load .svgz file, how can I convert it to .svg file to load?

Tags: android, xml, svg

I need to edit the svg pictures with PainterSVG, but it only loads .svg file, and some of the files I received are .svgz

Question: how can I convert those .svgz files into .svg files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svgz is a g-zipped svg file. Try to rename xyfile.svgz into xyfile.svg.gzip and extract the file (or, if you have a tool to unzip gzip with whatever ending, just use it).

note: use gzip, not zip.